# Force overwrite in BiqQuery extract_table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using the BigQuery Python API.

When creating a table from a query, BiqQuery's `JobConfig` has an option to set

```
job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
```

However, when using `extract_table` to export a table to GCS, I use `ExtractJobConfig` for the config. This latter doesn't seem to have a `WriteDisposition` at all, and in practice doesn't seem to write when the file exists.

Is there any way to force overwrite in this case?

Comment: Note: it's possible that this behaviour _does_ exist by default, but the system can take a while (> 1 hr) to transfer/update the files. Any clarity would be welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I could see in all the documentations Ive found ([[1]](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/0.32.0/bigquery/reference.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig), [[2]](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/JobConfigurationExtract.html), [[3]](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig.destination_format)), this specific kind of job does not provide any option regarding write disposition. Despite that, it seems that the default mode is overwriting. As I could reproduce, when you create a different job to export the same file, the file is replaced.
I would like to ask you for providing your code so I can reproduce the problem with more accuracy and give you a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for your research, but this should be a comment since it doesn't answer the question. Do you know what the default behaviour is?

Comment: Josh, sorry I could not add a comment because of my reputation. The default mode is overwriting, and I did not find anything about changing this mode. As I could reproduce here, if you create another job with a different id to export a file with the same name, the file will be replaced.